# Why does Msgbox corrupt Date variable

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Not sure what the real issue is. Used the code below to isolate issue. When run test, get run-time error. When comment out `MsgBox dDate2`, code runs fine. Why?

Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.1

Microsoft Excel for Mac 16.48

> Run-time error '6'  Overflow

```
Sub IssueMsgBox()
    Dim dTemp As Double
    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim dDate2 As Date
    Dim dDate3 As Date
    dDate = DateSerial(2021, 5, 1)
    dDate2 = WorksheetFunction.EDate(dDate, 1)
    MsgBox dDate2
    dDate3 = WorksheetFunction.EDate(dDate, 1)
    MsgBox dDate3
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of dDate2 when it errors? http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm#:~:text=Regardless%20of%20how%20you%20have,And%20times%20the%20same%20way.&text=Excel%20stores%20dates%20and%20times%20as%20a%20number%20representing%20the,tttttt%20.   This may help? if numeric

Comment: The posted code works fine for me, is there any other code?

Comment: I also had no problems copy/paste this code into a new workbook. Have you tried you above test code in a new workbook or just as a new procedure in your existing book?

Comment: `Microsoft Excel for Mac 16.48 | Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.1` Unable to reproduce the issue in the said config.